# Custom helper class not loading in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, helper

I am currently running into a problem when trying to use a custom helper class in Laravel 4.
I've created a folder in `app/libraries` which has a custom class MenuComposer.

app/libraries/folder/MenuComposer.php

```
<?php
    namespace 'folder\MenuComposer'

    class MenuComposer {
      // Code here
    }
```

I've edited composer.json to autoload the `app/libraries` folder and ran the dump-autoload command in console.

composer.json

```
    "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/libraries"
    ]
},
```

And finally I call the class like so:

```
View::composer('layouts.back', 'folder/MenuComposer');
```

Whatever I try, Laravel keeps returning the message `Class 'MenuComposer' not found`

Does anyone here know what the problem might be?

Comment: Have you tried "composer dump-autoload"?

Comment: As stated in my post: Yes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your namespace should be declared as the following rather than with quotes:

```
namespace folder\MenuComposer;
```

Composer dump-autoload then generates the following in your "/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap":

```
'folder\\MenuComposer\\MenuComposer' => $baseDir . '/app/libraries/folder/MenuComposer.php'
```

Which would indicate the class can be reached at:

```
folder/MenuComposer/MenuComposer
```

Hope this helps!